# How to print iteration number in Pepper-Box plain text config?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to print iteration number in pepper-box plain text config and i tried Counter config element of jmeter but during execution it is not replacing iteration number. Like if i am using ${counter} so in execution it is printing ${counter}.
I am using counter config element because i need iteration number in some format like 00001,00002,00003 etc.

I also tried to use function like Counter(TRUE,) but it is just replacing first iteration number and not increasing it. Only first iteration number printing in all next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In Pepper-Box sampler you can only use a limited subset of [built-in template functions](http://%20https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#schema-template-functions) having different syntax.

You can try doing something like:

```
{{org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().get("counter")}}
```

or if you want to share your script with others you can consider implementing a [custom function](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#custom-functions)

Check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article for more information on building a Kakfa test plan using JMeter

Comment: I tried but it was printing "null" then i tried in modified way {{org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().getIteration()}} it is printing iteration number in 1, 2,3 etc. but i am still trying for required format like 00001,00002,00003 etc